# Creating a dropdown menu in django form based on user model

Tags: python, django

Hello i have the following model and form

models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```py
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "user", "notes"]
```

How can i create a dropdown menu based on the builtin users in django, so that in my project form for user, i would have a drop down menu for the users instead of a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to

```py
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), empty_label="Select a user")

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'notes']
```

Don't forget to import `User`
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: In his model, didn't use the User model, used CharField.

Comment: True, I didn't notice that. I assume from the context of the question, it should be a FK. If not I will change my answer.

Comment: I based on your response and added the model updates in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the model to use User model and update form.

#### New `models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
```

#### New `forms.py`

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Project, User


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), empty_label="Select a user")

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'notes']
```

Comment: Wow thats perfect, exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much. I just had one quick question, is there a way in the forms.py to exclude one specific user?

Comment: You can change the queryset, for example, use filter instead of all or use exclude, or create a custom function to get an specific queryset with options for choices

Comment: @djangonewbie123 your problem was fixed? if my answer is correct, please confirm this with the check